# Managed C pointer does not release when finish its instant

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, managed

I have a problems that make a lagre data from the Managed C and use in the C# for the UI.

Here is the example:

Managed side:

```
public ref class c1
{
public:
    c1(void);
    ~c1(void);
    String ^Name;
    double dtata;
};


public ref class c2
{
public:
    c2(void);
    ~c2(void);
    !c2();
    String ^Name;
    List<c1^> ^arrData;

    void CreateData();
    void Clear();

};

void c2::CreateData()
{
    arrData=gcnew List<c1^>();
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        c1^ d=gcnew c1;
        arrData->Add(d);
    }
}
void c2::Clear()
{
    if(arrData)
    {
        delete arrData;
        arrData=nullptr;
    }
    GC::Collect();
}
```

C# side:

```
void Test()
{
using (c2 cx = new c2())
       {
         cx.CreateData();
         cx.Clear();
         cx.Dispose();

        }
}
```

The result is after call Test() function the memory rise from 4MB to 13MB

The question is why the cx does not release from the memory?

Thanks for look

Answer (score 0):

For C++/CLI, Destructors in a reference type perform deterministic clean up of your resources. Finalizers clean up unmanaged resources and can be called deterministically by the destructor or non-deterministically by the garbage collector. Please refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So you need implement the Finalizer to free the memory.